# KPTI support on AWS ubuntu kernels

Tags: 14.04, kernel, aws

I'm currently rolling in the released upgrades via restarts to our 14.04 LTS 3.13 kernels to mitigate against Meltdown, and have noticed that the currently published checks for KPTI support don't show here:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

$ uname -a
Linux 3.13.0-139-generic #188-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 14:43:09 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ grep 'CONFIG_PAGE_TABLE_ISOLATION=y' /boot/config-$( uname -r )
CONFIG_PAGE_TABLE_ISOLATION=y

$ grep -i 'cpu_insecure' /proc/cpuinfo

$ grep -i 'kpti' /proc/cpuinfo

$ grep -i 'kaiser' /proc/cpuinfo

$ dmesg | grep -i 'isolation'
```

Is this due to the nature of how virtualised kernels are implemented on AWS? Is the support there without actually being able to detect it at the CPU layer?

Comment: For reference, an updated Amazon Linux AMI is showing what I would expect: `# dmesg | grep -i 'isolation'
[    0.000000] Kernel/User page tables isolation: enabled`

Answer (score 0):

Just install linux-aws kernel, just had same issue and fixed with that.

BTW, it was just released 2 hours ago:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-aws/4.4.0-1010.10

Good luck!

Comment: That's not the kernel used by the Ubuntu AMIs on AWS though, I would've thought the default 14.04 AWS kernel, as it also has an update issued as 139, would include the changes. Doing that would also involve moving from the 3.13 to the 4.4 kernel, which we haven't tested at this stage.

Comment: Decided to chuck a support ticket Amazon's way, so will see what they say

Comment: BTW, one thing if you are using PV as virtualization type you will not see the kaiser or isolation output in your grep. For me the the only way to see such outputs was to upgrade to 4.4.0-1010.10 and in a HVM instance.

Comment: That could be it, as these are old PV instances, which means maybe the fix at the PV level all that is required. I'll test the same update of the 3.13.0 kernel on an HVM instance, thanks.

Comment: HVM instances on 3.13.0 show `Kernel/User page tables isolation: enabled` in dmesg as expected, though nothing in cpuinfo, but I imagine that's just a quirk of the kernel or the environment.

Comment: Check https://aws.amazon.com/security/security-bulletins/AWS-2018-013/ the PV instances can't be protected against Meltdown. So I recommend you to start moving those instances to HVM.